# how to avoid system overlay view being closed

Tags: android

My activity creates a system overlay view on the click of a button. I expect this view to remain visible over everything else till i close it on another button click in the activity.

The problem is Android automatically kills that view in a few seconds if i open couple of other applications. I know this is the expected behaviour of Android to manage it's resources. But is there a way to tell Android not to close this view? I tried creating the overlay in an IntentService, but it made no difference.

**View creation code :**

```
mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
mFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(mFrameLayout, params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use service to create your system overlay view.

Not IntentService, just extend Service.
Make it work even if app goes to backgroung by returning "START_STICKY"

Comment: As mentioned in OP, it made no difference.

Comment: It works well even with `return START_NOT_STICKY`. I guess since a service's `onDestroy` is not automatically called after it's work is done, it is always in a `running` mode. So it gets a higher priority than an IntentService whose `onDestroy` is called automatically after it's work is done.

Comment: @faizal you are right. IntentService destroy self once task is over. return START_STICKY if you need to run service continuously for long time.if system needs to kill your service, it starts service as the resources are available.